# Is there a way to set colors of terminal based of what profile is being used in my bashrc file? On Centos 7.5

Tags: centos, terminal, gnome-terminal

I have set the colors of my username and the colors of my directory in my bashrc file with the lines

```
export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\[\033[38;5;2m\][\u@\h-\t\[$(tput sgr0)\] \[$(tput sgr0)\]\[$(tput bold)\]\[\033[38;5;2m\]\W]\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\] \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;35:' ; export LS_COLORS #set color of directories
```

Which produces the colors in my terminal in the image below.
[image]

I like to have different terminals open and like to color code them depending on what I'm working on. My question is I would like to change the colors such as the directories depending on what terminal profile is being used.

At the moment, the colors I set above are applied to all profiles so if I switch to another profile I have, the username and directory colors remain the same like the image below and basically only the background color changes but I would like if this profile could use a different set of colors as well.

[image]

Is it possible I can have different colors set for different profiles.Basically insert an if else statement to implement in my bashrc file that will apply different colors depending on what terminal profile is used?

EDIT:
This is what I meant by profiles. It's a setting in my terminal. My gnome version is GNOME Shell 3.25.4 and the terminal I'm using is the GNOME Terminal version 3.22.1 "A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop Using VTE version 0.46.2 +GNUTLS"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is a profile? Is it something specific to a terminal emulator? If so, please add what it is.

Comment: Hey check my edits. A profle is a setting at the top of my terminal that I can select that allows me to set certain colors to it. It is the GNOME Terminal version 3.22.1 "A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop Using VTE version 0.46.2 +GNUTLS"

Comment: Have you tried it on a supported version of CentOS7?  It has version 3.28.3 of GNOME shell with many, many fixes.